# $split and return the first array element in mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
[
  {lecture : "427#Math"},
  {lecture : "217#Science"},
  {lecture : "7#History"},
  {lecture : "12#Music"}
]
```

Assume I have the database structure above. I want to return only the lecture code. 
What have I done so far?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$project: {"lecture": {$split: ["$lecture" , "#"]}}}
])
```

But this returns as collection `["427" , "Math"]`. How can I return only the lecture code which is the part that comes before the `#` character.

Answer (score 22):

You can use [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt) to return only first item from `$split` result:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$project: {"lecture": {$arrayElemAt:[{$split: ["$lecture" , "#"]}, 0]}}}
])
```